# Depending on completion of multiple parallel gulp tasks

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp

I have a complex NodeJS application, composed from several yarn workspace packages. The following gulpconfig.ts file defines a gulp build task for the entire set of packages:

```js
import { series, parallel, TaskFunction, src, dest } from 'gulp';
import gulpTslint from 'gulp-tslint';
import { createProject } from 'gulp-typescript';
import tslint, { Linter } from 'tslint';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { DestOptions } from 'vinyl-fs';
import { exec } from 'child_process';
import { promisify } from 'util';

const execPromise = promisify(exec);

interface GulpTasks {
  [key: string]: TaskFunction;
}

type TaskFunctionCallback = (error?: any) => void;

class Project {
  public projectFiles: NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;
  public constructor(
    public readonly projectDirectory: string,
    public readonly sourcemaps: boolean = false,
  ) {
    this.projectFiles = src('./src/**/*.ts', { cwd: projectDirectory, sourcemaps });
  }

  public lint(): this {
    this.projectFiles = this.projectFiles.pipe(
      gulpTslint({
        tslint,
        configuration: resolve(__dirname, 'tslint.json'),
        program: Linter.createProgram(
          resolve(this.projectDirectory, 'tsconfig.json'),
          this.projectDirectory,
        ),
      }),
    );

    return this;
  }

  public build(): this {
    const opts: DestOptions = {};
    if (this.sourcemaps) {
      opts.sourcemaps = true;
    }
    this.projectFiles = this.projectFiles
      .pipe(createProject(resolve(this.projectDirectory, 'tsconfig.build.json'))())
      .pipe(dest(resolve(this.projectDirectory, 'dist'), opts));

    return this;
  }
}

const buildDatabase = (cb: TaskFunctionCallback): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream =>
  new Project(resolve(__dirname, 'server/database')).build().projectFiles;

const buildSharedCommon = (cb: TaskFunctionCallback): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream =>
  new Project(resolve(__dirname, 'shared/common')).lint().build().projectFiles;
const buildSharedFrontoffice = (cb: TaskFunctionCallback): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream =>
  new Project(resolve(__dirname, 'shared/frontoffice')).lint().build().projectFiles;
const buildSharedBackoffice = (cb: TaskFunctionCallback): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream =>
  new Project(resolve(__dirname, 'shared/backoffice')).lint().build().projectFiles;

const buildClientCommon = (cb: TaskFunctionCallback): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream =>
  new Project(resolve(__dirname, 'client/common')).lint().build().projectFiles;
const buildClientFrontoffice = async (cb: TaskFunctionCallback): Promise<unknown> =>
  execPromise('yarn run build', { cwd: 'client/frontoffice' });
const buildClientBackoffice = async (cb: TaskFunctionCallback): Promise<unknown> =>
  execPromise('yarn run build', { cwd: 'client/backoffice' });

const buildServerCommon = (cb: TaskFunctionCallback): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream =>
  new Project(resolve(__dirname, 'server/common')).lint().build().projectFiles;
const buildServerFrontoffice = (cb: TaskFunctionCallback): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream =>
  new Project(resolve(__dirname, 'server/frontoffice')).lint().build().projectFiles;
const buildServerBackoffice = (cb: TaskFunctionCallback): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream =>
  new Project(resolve(__dirname, 'server/backoffice')).lint().build().projectFiles;

const tasks: GulpTasks = {
  build: parallel(
    buildDatabase,
    series(
      buildSharedCommon,
      parallel(buildSharedBackoffice, buildSharedFrontoffice),
      parallel(
        series(buildClientCommon, parallel(buildClientFrontoffice, buildClientBackoffice)),
        series(buildServerCommon, parallel(buildServerFrontoffice, buildServerBackoffice)),
      ),
    ),
  ),
};

export = tasks;
```

Because of how my application is structured, the buildServerCommon depends on buildDatabase. The buildDatabase however doesn't depend on anything, and takes a long time, which is why I start it in parallel with the rest.

With the setup above though, buildDatabase may (and does) finish later than buildServerCommon starts.

**How can I make buildServerCommon start only after buildDatabase and buildSharedCommon, but still have everything else start as early as possible?**

Basically, in my dependency tree:

- I have "client", "server" and "shared" package folders.
- "{client,server,shared}/common" is required by the "frontoffice" and "backoffice" packages in that same package folder.
- "shared/{common,frontoffice,backoffice}" is required by both the "client" and "server" of the respective package.
- "server/database" is special, in that it only exists in "server", and is required by "server/common".

I tried to use

```js
const tasks: GulpTasks = {
  build: series(
    parallel(buildSharedCommon, buildDatabase),
    parallel(buildServerCommon, buildSharedFrontoffice, buildSharedBackoffice),
    parallel(
      series(buildClientCommon, parallel(buildClientFrontoffice, buildClientBackoffice)),
      parallel(buildServerFrontoffice, buildServerBackoffice),
    ),
  ),
};
```

but that isn't optimal, since buildSharedFrontoffice and buildSharedBackoffice are not being compiled until buildDatabase is done, and from there the client is also needlessly delayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most optimal solution is to wait for all shared packages to be built and then fork in 2 parallel branches for client and server.

```js
const tasks: GulpTasks = {
    build: series(
        series(buildSharedCommon, parallel(buildSharedFrontoffice, buildSharedBackoffice)),
        parallel(
            series(buildClientCommon, parallel(buildClientFrontoffice, buildClientBackoffice)),
            series(buildDatabase, buildServerCommon, parallel(buildServerFrontoffice, buildServerBackoffice))
        )
    )
  };
```

Fastest/ideal execution path would be to spin 3 tasks in parallel, then to wait 2 out of 3 to complete, for two different continuations (client and server). That does not work out of the box with Gulp and would require your code to handle synchronization.

Comment: Your sequence is mostly like the one from my initial code (at the very top), except it moved "buildDatabase" into the server series, which I guess works, so thank you. Though in the end, I solved my issue by using project references in TypeScript, and having gulp execute tsc with the command line (because gulp-typescript doesn't support project references properly).

Answer (score 0):

If you used earlier versions of Gulp, be aware that the argument ordering of `serial()` differs from earlier versions using `task()`.   In particular the arguments to `serial()` are executed one after another in the order they are listed.

So, if you need `buildDatabase` to complete *before* `buildServerCommon`, they need to appear in the expected order inside the same `serial` function call.   I think you then need something more like this:

```
const tasks: GulpTasks = {
build: parallel(
    series( buildDatabase, buildServerCommon /* ... others? */ ),
    buildSharedCommon,
    buildSharedFrontoffice,
    // ... others?
    )
};
```

This of course assumes that buildSharedCommon and buildSharedFrontoffice have no dependencies on the message in the `serial()` block.

I look at it this way, in gulp 3, gulp tasks worked to figure-out the right build order from all the defined of `task` declaration, while in gulp 4, you have to be explicit using the new `series` and `parallel` constructs.   In that sense gulp has become more procedural than declarative.

Comment: buildServerCommon requires buildSharedCommon to have completed. However, buildSharedCommon doesn't require buildDatabase to have finished - they can start in parallel.... With your proposed setup, buildServerCommon might start before buildSharedCommon is ready. Sure, it might not, since buildDatabase takes longer, but I don't want to rely on that, as compilation times may change as the project develops.